# Could not access network location - Python Installer

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is probably going to be a simple answer but every time I try to install Python 3.6.6 it returns an error message.

> Could not access network location _\.

I've never encountered this before and have a Python 2.7.x version already installed. I'm currently trying to install it on a Windows 10 machine.

Comment: A simple search gives this https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/886549/you-receive-an-error-1606-error-message-when-you-try-to-install-or-rem looks like there is some issue with the registry.

Comment: @AmitDwivedi Would I have to edit registries for Python as the link you included is about issues with Microsoft programs.